# Distributive property with sum types and product types

Tags: type-theory

In [Philip Wadler's presentation, "Category Theory for the Working Hacker",](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/category-theory-propositions-principle) something confused me. At about 30:52, he says:

> We need this additional construct which is called distributivity. Here it is, right? It just says "given a choice of an A or a C and a choice of a B or a C, we can get a choice of an A or a B **and** a C."

This is shown on the slide as:

> $$ (A + C)\times(B + C) \cong (A + B) \times C $$

Is this correct? I have the following doubts about it:

- I think that, in Boolean algebra, the distributive property would give $ (A + C)\times(B + C) = (A \times B) + C $.
- Given a choice of an A or a C and a choice of a B or a C, we might choose C both times, giving us only a C and a C. For example, in Haskell:

```hs
    data AorC = ACA A | ACC C       -- sum type
    data BorC = BCB B | BCC C       -- sum type
    data Prod = Prod AorC BorC      -- product type
    cAndC = Prod (ACC c1) (BCC c2)  -- choose type C both times
```

Comment: That's where I'm getting stuck. Why can't you choose $ C $ both times? I'm getting my intuition, which is probably wrong, from Haskell, where if I have `data AorC = ACA A | ACC C; data BorC = BCB B | BCC C; data Prod = Prod AorC BorC`, where `AorC` and `BorC` are sum types and `Prod` is a product of the two sum types, and you can choose `C` in both with `Prod (ACC c1) (BCC c2)`.

Comment: You can tell from the explicit definition of the isomorphism on that slide that it is definitely a "typo", which would've been my expectation without looking at the slide.

Comment: @DerekElkins, OK, thanks. Time to rewatch it.

Comment: Polynomial types form a commutative semiring. Roughly, all the basic arithmetic laws for plus and times hold as expected, up to iso. It probably should be $(A\times C) + (B \times C) \simeq (A+B)\times C$, I guess.

Comment: @chi, want to write that as an answer so we can upvote it, and the question can be treated as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomial types (those obtained through $+,\times,0,1$ and type variables) form a commutative [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).

Basically, all the elementary arithmetic laws for $+$ and $\times$ hold as expected, up to (natural) isomorphism. These include commutativity, associativity, and distributivity of $\times$ over $+$.

More concretely, the distributive law is
$$ (A\times C)+(B\times C) \simeq (A+B)\times C$$
and I think this was the law that Philip Wadler meant to show.